# Difference in months between two dates

Tags: c#, datetime

Hi guys I need to get the difference between two dates, as a decimal.

Example: The difference between 13 Feb 2010 and 10 June 2011 is 15.87 months.

How would I accomplish this in c#?

Comment: A fractional number of months makes no sense, as months are different lengths.

Comment: There is no answer to this without a definition of 'length-of-month'.

Comment: what should be the answer for difference between Jan 1 2013 and Dec 31 2012? Please describe your use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want an approximation, you can do something as follows:

```
var first = new DateTime(2010, 2, 13);
var second = new DateTime(2011, 6, 10);
var result = second.Subtract(first).Days / (365.25 / 12);

Console.Write(result);
```

The result of this will be:

```
15,8357289527721
```

Comment: @johnnie because there is an additionnal day almost each 4 years

Comment: @johnnie In astronomy, the Julian year is a unit of time, defined as 365.25 days of 86400 SI seconds each (no leap seconds). It gives a bit more precision. If you didn't use the .25, the result would be 16, and not a 15.83...

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure.

Comment: It's only an approximation because you don't consider the startDate and endDate's real months. Depending on what the OP wants, it can do the trick ... or not :)

Comment: Actually, since we are living by the Gregorian calendar, 365.2425 is a  better choice.

Answer (score 2):

```
   public static int diffMonths(this DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
            return (startDate.Year * 12 + startDate.Month + startDate.Day/System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(startDate.Year, startDate.Month))
                    - (endDate.Year * 12 + endDate.Month + endDate.Day/System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(endDate.Year, endDate.Month));
    }
```

It calculates with [DaysInMonth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) how far you've advanced in the month, and substracts endDate - startDate

Comment: NB you can drop the `-1`s as they cancel.

Comment: @Rawling totally right, I wrote it directly how I would calculate it, but the 2 -1 can be dropped :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string fmt = "yyyy-MM-dd";
DateTime first = DateTime.Today;

for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++)
{
    DateTime second = first.AddMonths(3).AddDays(i);


    int wholeMonths = ((second.Year - first.Year) * 12) + second.Month - first.Month;
    DateTime firstPlusWholeMonths = first.AddMonths(wholeMonths);

    double fractMonths;
    if (firstPlusWholeMonths == second) fractMonths = wholeMonths;
    else
    {
        double diff = second.Subtract(firstPlusWholeMonths).TotalDays;
        fractMonths = wholeMonths + (diff * 12 / 365.25);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("From {0} to {1} is {2} months.", first.ToString(fmt), second.ToString(fmt), fractMonths.ToString("0.00000000"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.
But you need exact answer 15.87 months you have to separately maintain enum of number of days in month
           DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2010, 02, 13);
           DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2011,06,10);

```
       TimeSpan ts = dt2.Subtract(dt1);
       double days = (double)ts.TotalHours / (24);
       double months = days / 30.4;
```